# Spring Boot: process a html file with thymeleaf without controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to serve internationalized html pages with my Spring Boot application and I am using Thymeleaf with `messages_XX.properties` for i18n. I would prefer accessing these as http://localhost:8080/some/path/test.html and having them in e.g. `/src/main/resources/html` but I am unable to configure Spring Boot to process a page using thymeleaf by default.

As a temporary workaround I have a controller with

```
@RequestMapping(value="**/*.html")
public String serve(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String res = req.getRequestURI().substring(0, req.getRequestURI().length() - 5);
    res = res.substring(1);
    return res;
}
```

This works for me now: http://localhost:8080/some/path/file.html processes and serves `src/templates/some/path/file.html` but can I just configure somewhere that `src/resources/html` are to be PROCESSED by thymeleaf and then served?

So far I have tried

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/html/
```

in `application.properties` but it does not seemed to work for me.

Environment:
`spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.RELEASE`,
`spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE`,
`thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are cutting of the .html in:

```
String res = req.getRequestURI().substring(0, req.getRequestURI().length() - 5);
```

You should probably set

```
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Or with Configuration:

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/html/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Comment: I do not mind cutting the .html part. I do not want to have this controller in the first place. Anyway, seems I will have to live with it.